# Static Declaration of a structure

Tags: c, static, initialization

I'm trying to define a static structure and initialize its values once when it is declared, but I'm not really sure how I would do so.

I'm calling a function in a loop, and I want to initialize a `timespec` (specifically the `tv_sec` value) to `0` (sort of a default value) the first time the function is called, but never again.

I know I can do this with integers and other simple data types by doing:
`static int foo = 0`

But I want to do the same with with a structure, so its not so simple.

Essentially, I want to do this: `static struct timespec ts.tv_sec = 0;` But, that illegal, so I need to know the legal form (if it exists).

Help?

Comment: Structs can be initialised using `{...}`, is that what you mean?

Comment: @Matt that might work...

Comment: @Matt yeah, that did, thanks, put it in an answer and I'll give you credit

Comment: The good lazy news is: If you want to zero-initialise a static object, you don't need to do anything. It's zero-initialised by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregate objects, like structs or arrays, are initialized with `= { ... }` initializers. You can either supply initializers for consecutive members of the struct beginning with the first, or use C99 tagged approach

```
static struct timespec ts = { .tv_sec = 0 };
```

Note BTW that `= { ... }` approach is more universal than it might seem at first sight. Scalar objects can also be initialized with such initializers

```
static int foo = { 0 };
```

Also note that `= { 0 }` will zero out all data fields in the aggregate object, not just the first one.

Finally keep in mind that objects with static storage duration are always zero-initialized automatically, meaning that if you just declare

```
static struct timespec ts;
```

you are already guaranteed to end up with zero-initialized object. No need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A static object, no matter if it's a struct, union, array or basic type is always zero initialized in the absence of an explicit initializer. Just use

```
static struct timespec foo;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing with an "invalid" value, you can simply use another variable:

```
static struct timespec ts;
static int ts_initialized = 0;

if (!ts_initialized) {
    init_ts(&ts);
    ts_initialized = 1;
}
```

Advantages:
1. Somewhat more clear.
2. No need to find a "magic" value, which will never be used.